# Recursive webscraper not printing text from pages to screen using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7, 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am building a recursive webscraper that seemed to be working when only extracting the text from a single page, however does not appear to be working when scraping multiple pages. The code is below:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal3"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), 
                  follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')
    ]

    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        scripts = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for scripts in scripts:
            body = response.xpath('//p').extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)
            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')  


execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal3'])
```

A sample of the output I am getting from this is below:

```
2014-07-25 19:31:32+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Players/133260/Show/Michael-Ngoo> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Players/14170/Show/Ishmael-Miller)
2014-07-25 19:31:33+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/160/Show/England-Charlton> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Players/10794/Show/Rafik-Djebbour)
2014-07-25 19:31:33+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.cafc.co.uk': <GET http://www.cafc.co.uk/page/Home>
2014-07-25 19:31:34+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/721465/Live/England-Championship-2013-2014-Nottingham-Forest-Charlton> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Players/10794/Show/Rafik-Djebbour)
2014-07-25 19:31:36+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/126/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/1426/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:36+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.fcsochaux.fr': <GET http://www.fcsochaux.fr/fr/index.php?lng=fr>
2014-07-25 19:31:37+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/976/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/1426/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:37+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.grenoblefoot38.fr': <GET http://www.grenoblefoot38.fr/>
2014-07-25 19:31:37+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.as.com': <GET http://www.as.com/futbol/articulo/leones-ponen-manos-obra-grenoble/20120713dasdaiftb_52/Tes>
2014-07-25 19:31:38+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/56/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/53/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:38+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.realracingclub.es': <GET http://www.realracingclub.es/default.aspx>
2014-07-25 19:31:39+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/125/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/146/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:39+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.asnl.net': <GET http://www.asnl.net/pages/club/entraineurs.html>
2014-07-25 19:31:40+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/425/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/24/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:40+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.dbu.dk': <GET http://www.dbu.dk/>
2014-07-25 19:31:42+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/282/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/50/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:42+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.fc-koeln.de': <GET http://www.fc-koeln.de/index.php?id=10>
2014-07-25 19:31:43+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/58/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/131/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:43+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.realvalladolid.es': <GET http://www.realvalladolid.es/>
2014-07-25 19:31:44+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/973/News> (referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/145/News)
2014-07-25 19:31:44+0100 [goal3] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.fifci.org': <GET http://www.fifci.org/>
```

I can understand the external links being filtered out as they out of the scope of the crawler, however what I cannot understand is why the results being returned is a 'DEBUG:' message and the link of the page, especially as there is a successful HTTP return code of 200 being printed for all these results.

Can anyone see what the issue is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have a single rule with `follow=True`:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
```

Comment: hi again. that seemed to work, however it's only returning the footer links from the page. i will need to have a look at the html and found how the text body is coded because '//p' is not working in this instance. thanks